# VBA - Add blank rows depending on (n+1)-(n) value then delete anything inbetween if less than a value

Tags: excel, vba, analysis

So I'm writing a VBA to try and automate some data analysis which will loop through the data and anytime the time difference in the row is more than a second delay (resolution of data is higher) it will add a blank row indicating a new 'test run' of data. Then I want to delete any rows (call RangeA) inbetween the blank rows if RangeA is say 2 seconds (i.e. a short test run that is meaningless).

I've managed to create some temperamental code that adds the blank rows, but it comes back with 'type mismatch' in my if statement.

I do then need to create a chart from this data later on, so I'm not sure if adding blank rows is the best way or it will cause issues later on.

EDIT - found that some cells had strings in them due to some macro I had messed around with earlier. So it now does seperate the data with a blank row, it's now a case of trying to eliminate anything in each block that is less than 2 seconds.

```
Sub dataSeperator()

    Dim rowStart As Long
    Dim rowEnd As Long
    Dim rowLoop As Long
    Dim FindColumn As Range

    rowStart = 3
    rowEnd = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count).row

    With Sheets("Data")
        Set FindColumn = Cells.Find(What:="Time", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    End With

      For rowLoop = rowEnd To rowStart Step -1

       With Sheets("Data").Cells(rowLoop, FindColumn.Column)

        If Cells(rowLoop - 1, FindColumn.Column) - Cells(rowLoop, FindColumn.Column) < -1 Then

            .EntireRow.Insert

        End If

    End With

Next rowLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Then I want to delete any rows (call RangeA) inbetween the blank rows if RangeA is say 2 seconds"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer still stands, but in my opinion you could improve the readability and simplicity of the code if you work as follows.  What do you think?:

```
Sub Seperator2()

    Const TableHeaderRowNumber As Long = 1

    Dim cellTableHeaderWithTime As Range
    Dim rngMyTable As Range
    Dim rngMyColumnOfTimes As Range

    Dim rowStart As Long
    Dim rowEnd As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long


    With Sheets("Data")

        Set cellTableHeaderWithTime = .Cells.Find(What:="Time", After:=.Cells(TableHeaderRowNumber, 1) _
                                                              , LookIn:=xlValues _
                                                              , LookAt:=xlWhole _
                                                              , MatchCase:=False)
        rowStart = TableHeaderRowNumber + 2
        rowEnd = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        Set rngMyTable = .Range(.Cells(rowStart, cellTableHeaderWithTime.Column), .Cells(rowEnd, cellTableHeaderWithTime.Column))

        ' Just get the column of cells you need to compare
        Set rngMyColumnOfTimes = Intersect(rngMyTable, cellTableHeaderWithTime.EntireColumn)


        For lngCounter = rngMyColumnOfTimes.Cells.Count To rowStart Step -1

            'rngMyTable(lngCounter) is shorthand for rngMyTable.item(lngCounter)
            With rngMyTable(lngCounter)

                Debug.Print .Address

                If .Offset(-1, 0) - .Value < -1 Then

                    .EntireRow.Insert

                End If

            End With


        Next lngCounter


    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
Seperator()

    Dim rowStart As Long
    Dim rowEnd As Long
    Dim rowLoop As Long
    Dim FindColumn As Range

    rowStart = 3

    With Sheets("Data")

        rowEnd = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row

        ' replaced "Cells" with ".cells"
        Set FindColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="Time", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    End With

      For rowLoop = rowEnd To rowStart Step -1

       With Sheets("Data").Cells(rowLoop, FindColumn.Column)

        ' Used .Value instead
        ' "Cells" refers to the active sheet!
        ' use  Sheets("Data").Cells instead
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(rowLoop - 1, FindColumn.Column) - .value  < -1 Then
        ' If Cells(rowLoop - 1, FindColumn.Column) - Cells(rowLoop, FindColumn.Column) < -1 Then


            .EntireRow.Insert

        End If

    End With

Next rowLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it wasn't working because some strings had made their way into the time column - that was my mistake. As for the deleting rows. My data will be split up into time segments, so like 1-40 seconds, blank row, 40-42 seconds, blank row, 42-90 seconds etc. What I want to do is delete the 40-42 seconds segment because it's only 2 seconds long.

Comment: Sorry i still don't understand.

Comment: Using cells not .cells could have causes it to fail though.